# How do I fill the gap between groups of vertices for 3D printing?

Tags: mesh, vertices, 3d-printing

I have a 3D model which i want to 3D print, it has a face and a hair mesh which i initially joined to export a single PLY format mesh to 3D color printing. But then i noticed that the face and the hair (which both can be separated again easily so don't worry about that) have a gap between them, see:
[image: Vertices of hair and face]
More detailed view:

[image: Gap]

What i want to do is to extend the hair so it joins with the face. Is there a way to do that? Something like making new edges to join vertices of both groups of vertices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like most things in computer science there's more than one solution

One way would be to do it by hand. Just extend the thing and boolean it. 
The answer I prefer is to use meshmixer(free) and make solid the two objects. It looks something like this afterwards
[image]

Is that what the question was about ?